# Unresolved reference: grgit

Tags: kotlin, gradle

This is my world server land plug-in, and I don't know much about gradle and kotlin.(Know some front-end, but every line is like a mountain)

I encountered a problem when compiling. It seems that I lack something called grgit.
How to solve this problem?

Or you can try to compile this [project](https://github.com/IntellectualSites/PlotSquared). If you succeed, don't forget to tell me your method. Thank you very much!

```kotlin
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

dependencies {
    // Expected everywhere.
    compileOnlyApi(libs.checkerqual)

    // Minecraft expectations
    compileOnlyApi(libs.guava)
    compileOnlyApi(libs.gson)

    // Platform expectations
    compileOnlyApi(libs.snakeyaml)

    // Adventure
    api(libs.adventure)
    api(libs.minimessage)

    // Guice
    api(libs.guice) {
        exclude(group = "com.google.guava")
    }
    api(libs.guiceassistedinject) {
        exclude("com.google.inject", "guice")
    }
    compileOnlyApi(libs.findbugs)

    // Plugins
    compileOnlyApi(libs.worldeditCore) {
        exclude(group = "bukkit-classloader-check")
        exclude(group = "mockito-core")
        exclude(group = "dummypermscompat")
    }
    testImplementation(libs.worldeditCore)
    compileOnlyApi(libs.fastasyncworldeditCore) { isTransitive = false }
    testImplementation(libs.fastasyncworldeditCore) { isTransitive = false }

    // Logging
    compileOnlyApi(libs.log4j)

    // Other libraries
    api(libs.prtree)
    api(libs.aopalliance)
    api(libs.pipeline) {
        exclude(group = "com.google.guava")
    }
    api(libs.arkitektonika)
    api(libs.paster)
}

tasks.processResources {
    filesMatching("plugin.properties") {
        expand(
            "version" to project.version.toString(),
            "commit" to rootProject.grgit.head().abbreviatedId, // The error points here
            "date" to rootProject.grgit.head().dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy.MM.dd")) // The error points here
        )
    }
}
```

[Problems arising](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spBOD.png)

Address of this project: https://github.com/IntellectualSites/PlotSquared

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to declare the grgit variable before using it, that's why you're getting the error.

Add plugin for grgit in the `plugins{}` block:

```
 id("org.ajoberstar.grgit") version "4.0.2"
```

Import Grgit like this:

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit
```

Then, declare the variable grgit like this:

```
val grgit = Grgit.open(mapOf("currentDir" to project.rootDir))
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, but I still don't know where I should modify. There are three build.gradle.kts files in the project:
1: /build.gradle.kts
2: /Core/build.gradle.kts
3: /Bukkit /build.gradle.kts

Comment: According to your reasons, should I do this:
Add to the plugin block of the /Build.gradle.kts file:
`id("org.ajoberstar.grgit") version "4.0.2"`
Add the following to the error reported /Core/build.gradle.kts file:
`import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit` and `val grgit = Grgit.open(mapOf("currentDir" to project.rootDir))`

Comment: If you need grgit in both modules (Core and Bukkit), then add the plugin in the build.gradle.kts file in the project directory (not the ones in Core or Bukkit folders), else, add it in the Core/build.gradle.kts file. And, the imports shouldbe added in the error reporting file.